# In jquery how to get a matching element with a defined property(attribute) value

Tags: jquery

Below is my jQuery code, I want to get that `li` which has `data-target="5"`.
But my loop not enter in if condition even if there is a `li` with `data-target="5"`.

```js
var target = 5;
$("ul.menu-content li.collapsed").each(function() {
  if ($(this).is('[data-target]') == target) {
    $(this).removeClass('collapsed').find('a').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: i got the reason why its not matching, its always showing first li with [data-target]. loop not working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need get `data-target` using [`.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) and compare its value.

```
if($(this).data('target') == target)
```

Or, You can directly use [Attribute value selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and the code can be improved as

```
$("ul.menu-content li.collapsed[data-target=" + target+"]")
  .removeClass('collapsed')
  .find('a')
  .addClass('active');
```